# How to read/change SELinux context on mounted ext4 image from non-SELinux system?

Tags: arch-linux, ext4, selinux

I have a Linux system (Arch Linux) without SELinux support. I would not like to configure such support on my system.
Now, I have an ext4 volume image which is known to have some SELinux context set on its files. I need to read and change that context for certain files.
When I mount this image and `ls -lZ` it, I get a `?` instead of context.

How do I access & change SELinux context on files if I don't have SELinux enabled systemwide? If this is impossible, then which is minimal SELinux configuration which will not influence overall system but will allow me to change contexts within a mounted image?

Comment: The reason I need this was modifying Android firmware. The answer below works fine.

Answer (score 5):

SELinux context is stored in file's extended attributes (`xattr`, `man 5 attr`). Tools for working with them are available in `core/attr` package.

Attributes, including SELinux context, can be retrieved with `getfattr`. There is a caveat though: by default `getfattr` lists only attributes from `user.` namespace; and `selinux` attribute we need is in `security` namespace. So we need to pass `-m -` option to request attributes for all namespaces (`-d` is to dump values as well as names):

```
$ getfattr -m - -d bin/sh
# file: bin/sh
security.selinux="u:object_r:system_file:s0"
```

To change selinux context, I used `setfattr` tool, which required root privileges:

```
$ sudo setfattr -n security.selinux -v u:object_r:shell_exec:s0 bin/sh
$ getfattr -m - -d bin/sh
# file: bin/sh
security.selinux="u:object_r:shell_exec:s0"
```

Comment: Works marvelously for files. But what about symbolic links?

Comment: @AdamBliss If you want to change attributes (e.g. selinux context) for symlink itself rather than referenced file, just pass `-h` or `--no-dereference` option to `getfattr` or `setfattr`.

Comment: Thanks. That does work. Any idea why `xattr` doesn't work on symbolic links, or why its man page claims that symlinks don't have extended attributes?

Comment: There are various namespaces of extended attributes. The sentence about attrs not being supported for symlinks is in `User extended attributes` paragraph of `xattr(7)` manpage, it only applies to attributes in `user.*` namespace. Other namespaces, like security and others, are valid and hence are supported by `setfattr`.